# Rename a column based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of four dataframes: df_all = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

As a sample, they look like this:

df1:

```
Name     Dates        a

Apple   5-5-15        NaN
Apple   6-5-15        42
Apple   6-5-16        36
Apple   6-5-17        36

 df2: 

Name     Dates          a

Banana   5-5-15        85
Banana   6-5-15        NaN
Banana   6-6-15        100
Banana   6-5-16        18
```

I want to merge on "Dates", which I achieve in the following manner:

```
for cols in df_all:
    cols = cols.drop(['Name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
a = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on = 'Date').merge(df3, how='left',  on = 'Date').merge(df4, how='left',  on = 'Date')
```

This gives me exactly what I want. However, the columns are renamed as `a_x, a_y, a_x, a_y`
This sample below shows what happens when I merge only df1 and df2.

```
Dates         a_x        a_y

5-5-15        NaN         85
6-5-15        42         NaN
6-6-15        NaN        100
6-5-16        36          18
6-5-17        36         NaN
```

Before the merge, I want to rename column `a` based on the value in Name (apple, or banana), and I want to automate it as much as possible to rename all dataframe column `'a'` to the value in their column `'Name'`

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the column name in your first for loop before you drop that column.

```
for cols in df_all:
    name = cols['Name'][0]
    cols.drop(['Name'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    cols.rename(columns={'a':name},inplace=True)
a = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on = 'Date').merge(df3, how='left',  on = 'Date').merge(df4, how='left',  on = 'Date')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try do with `concat` and modify your dataframe

```
df=pd.concat([x.set_index(['Name','Dates']).a.unstack(level=0) for x in listdf])
```

Or combine then then `pivot_table`

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).pivot_table(index='Dates',columns='Name',values='a',aggfunc='first')
Name    Apple  Banana
Dates                
5-5-15    NaN    85.0
6-5-15   42.0     NaN
6-5-16   36.0    18.0
6-5-17   36.0     NaN
6-6-15    NaN   100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a rename before you drop the name column. Since all names are the same in a dataframe, you can get it from the first line:

```
for cols in df_all:
    cols.rename(columns={'a': cols.at[0, 'Name']}, inplace=True)
    cols = cols.drop(['Name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the process of merging the dataframe by renaming the columns before merging and then using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to merge all dataframes in `df_all`:

```
from functools import reduce 

# rename column a
df_all = [df.rename(columns={'a': df.pop('Name').iloc[0]}) for df in df_all]

# merge all dataframes
merged = reduce(lambda d1, d2: pd.merge(d1, d2, on=['Dates'], how='left') , df_all)
```

---

```
# print(merged)
# sample result after merging df1 & df2 

    Dates  Apple  Banana
0  5-5-15    NaN    85.0
1  6-5-15   42.0     NaN
2  6-5-16   36.0    18.0
3  6-5-17   36.0     NaN
```